# Understanding ergodic/mixing group actions and flows

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, mixing

Setup: Let $X$ be some probability space with probability measure $\mu$ (so $\mu(X)=1$). And let $G$ be a one real perameter topological group so $G=\{g_s:s\in\mathbb{R}\}$, and for the sake of simplicity let's assume the topology on $G$ corresponds to the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ with a homeomorphism given by $g_s\mapsto s$. Lastly we have a map $G\to MPCT(X)$ (space of continuous measure preserving transforms of $X$) where the resulting map $G\times X\to X$ is continuous in both perameters.

We say $G$ is mixing if for every sequence $\{g_n\}$ with $g_n$ eventually leaving any compact set we have $$\mu(g_n^{-1}(A)\cap B)\to\mu(A)\mu(B)$$ for any two measurable sets $A,B\subset X$. Now let $\langle g_s\rangle$ be the subgroup generated by an element $g_s\in G$. Here is my question, if we have that $\langle g_s\rangle$ is mixing for any generator $g_s\in G$, does that imply $G$ is mixing? It doesn't seem like it should necessarily but I can't construct a counter example.

Comment: Suppose $G = \mathbb{R}$. Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be $f(x) = \mu(x^{-1}(A)\cap B)-\mu(A)\mu(B)$. Then $f$ is continuous, and $f(n\alpha) \to 0$ as $n \to \pm \infty$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. It's an easy exercise using Baire Category to prove that then $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$. Having a sequence $\{g_n\}$ that eventually leaves any compact set is equivalent to having a sequence $(x_n)_n$ tending to $\pm \infty$ and you're asking whether $f(x_n) \to 0$; this follows from the mentioned exercise.